# making R scripts. Problem with special characters

Tags: r, rstudio

I've got an R script that makes other R scripts & am having troubles with special characters showing up properly in RStudio.
For example:

`cat("Air Temp.Air Temperature (°C) - Hourly", file = "testing.R")`

The degrees C symbol appears correctly when I open testing.R in notepad++, and notepad++ shows the endoding to be ANSI.

When I open testing.R in RStudio, the degrees C symbol appears as '?'. My RStudio default encoding is set to 'ask'.

(RStudio v1.4.1103, Windows10)

Comment: Try a newer version of RStudio. It works fine for me in 1.4.1717. Does RStudio ask you what encoding is being used?

Comment: Updated to 1.4.1717 & get the same behaviour. It doesn't ask about encoding. Can I specify which encoding type 'testing.R' gets opened with? (without globally changing the encoding type)

Comment: Did you re-run both steps after updating? What is your `sessionInfo()$locale` setting? Maybe try an explict encoding like `cat("Air Temp.Air Temperature (°C) - Hourly", file = file("testing.R", encoding = "UTF8"))` or `cat("Air Temp.Air Temperature (°C) - Hourly", file = file("testing.R", encoding = "latin-1"))`

Comment: Thanks for this. ''cat("Air Temp.Air Temperature (°C) - Hourly", file = file("testing.R", encoding = "UTF8"))'' worked. In my full script I'd been using 'write'. Using 'write_lines' fixed the issue.